# alter variable in console while debuggin nodejs with --inspect

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

**I was crazy searching, how modify one variable via console while debuggin and I can't, I don't know how to access it.**

**what I'm doing**

1. Run nodejs  like `node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9000 test.js`
2. open `chrome://inspect/#devices`
3. Open terminal and see code and console of my nodejs
4. try to modify one variable that is declared in file, like `var x = 10;` to `x = 20`

but I can't see how to do it...

**Example code:**

```
var x = 10;
setInterval(fuction(){
    console.log(x)
})
```

**Example with image :**

[image]

Comment: Try switching the console context (it's where node[60517] is displayed on your screenshot).

Comment: @wOxxOm when I try It, only appear one option to select... I think It is the actual node...